# Signing process in web application security

Tags: security, rest

I'm trying to understand the basics of security. To do that I started to develop a project in which I secure a REST API.

In this project I try to ensure integrity and confidentiality; to do that I want the client to encrypt and then sign the message.

For what I've been reading, you use a private key in the signature process to ensure non-repudiation.

I developed a Java client that encrypts and signs and it seems to be working okay. However, now I'm trying to develop a Javascript client, here I have some problems because I'm not sure how to do the signing process.

How do I manage to have a key to sign the messages?
Is there a formal/standard way to achieve signing in web clients?

Comment: You should consider using SSL or other transport-layer security rather than implement/utilize a crypto stack in JS and work on the application level.   That way is possible (I've done it for a special-needs project), but there is Madness and Insanity down that road.

Comment: I read [this](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2005/04/25/END-TO-END-SECURITY-OR-WHY-YOU-SHOULDN-T-DRIVE-YOUR-MOTORCYCLE-NAKED/) post that gives a good explanation about end to end security.
For what I understand there could be some inscances where the message is not safe (after the message is received for example).
Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Unless you have specific security requirements (specific threat models you are anticipating and trying to mitigate), you don't have to worry about "end to end" security the way this author means it - it sounds like in your case you're just processing requests in the browser in JS, which means this is the only application that will ever touch the plaintext.  You must trust the browser as it is the immediate user agent.  Compare with the example of an enterprise architecture message queue the author gives...

Comment: Thats true, but I'm trying to do this just to learn how to manage crypto in a browser, even though I dont need it I want to give it a try just to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this library if you want to do encryption from JavaScript: 
https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

Calculating a SHA256 hash is as simple as:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha256.js"></script>
<script>
    var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256("Message");
</script>
```

For using digital signatures from JavaScript look at this: 
http://techblog.bozho.net/digital-signatures-with-javascript/

Comment: For what I understand, if I want to achieve non-repudiation the message should be hashed and then encrypted using a private key. There is where my problem appears, I still dont figure out how to encrypt using a private key in a web client, Im pretty sure im missing something.

Comment: Yes, for non-repudiation you need digital certificates. I've added another link to my answer which shows how you can do signatures.

Comment: I've been reading and I think I'll try to use what you suggested (for signatures) for older browser versions. Last versions of IE, FF and chrome seem to have the [Web Crypto API](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI) implemented so I'll check how it works and try to use it.